# How to create a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have several fields on my form and I need to store them in table named `dbo.UploadFilesProject`, after user input. For this purpose I want to use a stored procedure.

Columns in the database table:

```
@ProjectId (int, Input, No default)
@FileName (varchar(75), Input, No default)
@FilePath (varchar(500), Input, No default)
@UploadedDate (date, Input, No default)
@IsActive (bit, Input, No default)
@UpdatedBy (varchar(75), Input, No default)
@ClientId (int, Input, No default)
```

Please, tell me how can I implement these requirements?

Comment: I assume you need to create table at first and then write stored procedure to fill it with data? How to create SP is written on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: its form fields if some one enter value this fields form value store database   this concept i want.  i need to create table?

Comment: Yes, at first you must create table (to store data), then create SP to write data in table. You can also write SP that will create table if it don't exist and then write data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [CREATE TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) use something like this (also you may need some Primary Key on this table, PK must consist of some unique column(s)):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UploadFilesProject (
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1),
    ProjectId int,
    FileName varchar(75),
    FilePath varchar(500),
    UploadedDate date,
    IsActive bit,
    UpdatedBy varchar(75),
    ClientId int,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) -- add some PK
)
```

Then [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to write data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UploadFilesProjectFill
    @ProjectId int,
    @FileName varchar(75),
    @FilePath varchar(500),
    @UploadedDate date,
    @IsActive bit,
    @UpdatedBy varchar(75),
    @ClientId int
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.UploadFilesProject VALUES
    (@ProjectId, @FileName, @FilePath, @UploadedDate, @IsActive, @UpdatedBy, @ClientId)
END
```